# Spring Boot FileLİst download zip

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, download

in spring boot project, I want to download all the files of he user into a single zip.

```
@GetMapping("/allFilePerson/{personId}")
public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> allFilePerson(@PathVariable(value = "personId") Integer personId) {

    List<file> fileList=service.findByFileId(personId);
    
    ....
}
```

This code single file download.But convert to fileList zip or rar.

```
@RequestMapping("/downloadFile/{fileId}")
public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> handleFileDownloadPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable(value = "fileId") Integer fileId) throws IOException, Exception {
      
            File file = service.getFile(fileId);
            ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

            InputStream stream = null;
                stream = new FileInputStream(file.getFilePath());

                //write the file to the file specified
                int bytesRead = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format(" attachment; filename=\"%s\"", file.getFileName()));

                while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer, 0, 8192)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                out.flush();
                out.close();
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

Comment: And what seems to be the problem? If you need to zip a file check out https://www.baeldung.com/java-compress-and-uncompress

Comment: Thank you:)  I have one more question. I want to use UTF8 in thefilename but the code below doesn't work.
        String zipName = person.getName() + "_" + person.getSurname() + ".zip";
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(zipName);
        ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);